# How to change the background image of tab bar in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabbar

I am develop in objective-C. I want to change the tab bar background like the following picture:
[image]

And the code is like the following:

```
UIImage *tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbaritem_background.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
```

But after setting the background image , the background is not at the correct place like the following:

[image]

The background image should be place at the bottom like the background in above picture.

Did I missing something ? Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do these help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909379/setting-a-background-image-for-a-tabbar  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413651/how-to-set-a-custom-background-image-to-tabbar .   If not, you may need to explain the problem more clearly.

Comment: Show we your tabbaritem_background.png

Comment: @SonofaBeach , I have try the code in the link , but it is the same...the background image should be place at the bottom like the background in the top of picture.

Comment: Are you saying that it is placed somewhere else, or that it is not appearing anywhere at all?   (The latter, I think?)  Please log the following, to make sure they are as expected:  tabBarBackground (UIImage) & the tabBar itself.

Comment: Do you have an image to match the resolution of your device (eg, 2x for a retina, or 3x for a recent iPad)?

Answer (score 1):

I think is somewhere you go wrong, check if is this steps:

1. In the storyboard change the ViewController's background color for test.

[image]

2. Embed the ViewController in Tab Bar Controller

[image]

3. In the `ViewController.m` you can set the tabbar bacground color:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]]; // Here you can set the converted color form image, make sure the imageSize fit.
   }
   ```
4. The result is below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the method `- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode` you can try, because your backgroudimage's size is not equal to tabbar'size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to change your image to a ScaleImage.

```
+(UIImage *)getScaleImageNamed:(NSString *)name{
    UIImage *nomalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:name];

    CGFloat hInset = floorf(nomalImage.size.width / 2);
    CGFloat vInset = floorf(nomalImage.size.height / 2);

    UIImage *res = [nomalImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(vInset, hInset, vInset, hInset)];

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps you may miss, hope that can help.

1. Make sure you have imported the background image (e.g. in `Assets.xcassets`)
2. Use `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` to resize the background image
3. Put the `UIAppearance` settings in `AppDelegate.m`:

   ```
   [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbaritem_background.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]];
   ```